# How can I rewrite the following statement using ng-options?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following block of Angular/HTML which is working fine however my issue is that after a selection I can only access the `value` of the selected option which is defined as `value.id`, rather than an array of objects.

What is the best-practise method to rewrite the below chunk using only `ng-option` with the `group by` statement on `select`?

```
<select name="device[ [[$index]] ]" ng-model="selectedModel" ng-change="loadModelImage(selectedModel, $index)">
    <option value="">Model</option>
    <optgroup ng-repeat="model in manufacturerModels" label="[[model.model]]">
        <option ng-repeat="variant in model.variants" value="[[model.id]]">[[model.model + ' - ' + variant.memory + ' - ' + variant.colour]]
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <select ng-model="modelSelected"
           ng-options="model.SubArray.name group by model.type 
                       for model in manufacturerModels" 
           value="model.id"> 
    </select>
```

See, ng-model **modelSelected** will assign the option selected, it'll return an object of the object type you passed. 
**model.SubArray.name** will be the string you want to display, like : '[[mode.model + variant.memory + variant.colour', I recommend you to create a field with these three values, and then, instead of **model.name**, you put the new variable created, like **model.createdFieldWithThreeNames**

 Then you have the **group by**, grouping by type, name, year, whatever it matches between the data.
 for **model** (the alias name) and finally **in** the array you want to use, in this case, **manufacturerModels**.

Post some feedback to us see if you got it.

Comment: Modifying the way data is spit out from the API is not an option

Comment: You're not modifying anything, if you mean  **model.createdFieldWithThreeNames**, that's just a way to show what your user will see, but if you can't change that, that's going to be a problem to show the three variables like you wanted, quite not possible. Check out the API docs and see for further information. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select

Comment: Variants is a sub-array in model, if I created a new field for each object inside variants following the three names format, how would I display that as the values of the dropdown?

Comment: I edited the answer, check that out. You just put **model.SubArray.VariableName**.